# How to filter and aggregate data from one collection into another format using MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have one collection named 'ctrlcharts'.
e.g.

```
{  
   "_id" : ObjectId("57fc695492af567031246736"),
   "deviceId" : "A001",
   "sensorId" : "S003",
   "time" : "2016/10/11 12:23:50",
   "charts" : [ 
      {
        "sensor" : "ch_11",
        "value" : 120
      },
      {
        "sensor" : "ch_12",
        "value" : 150
      }
    ]
}
```

How to filter `"sensor" : "ch_11"` and aggregate data from one collection into another format using MongoDB

e.g.

```
{         
   "time" : "2016/10/11 12:23:50",
   "sensor" : "ch_12",
   "value" : 150       
}
```

I tried below code

```
db.ctrlcharts.aggregate([
    { $match: {"deviceId" : "A001", "sensorId" : "S003", "time" : "2016/10/11 12:23:50"}},
    { $project: { 
        _id: 0,
        time : 1 , 
        sensor : "$charts.sensor"
        value : "$charts.value"
      }
    } 
])
```

But I got the result as

```
{         
   "time" : "2016/10/11 12:23:50",
   "sensor" : ["ch_11","ch_12"],
   "value" : [120,150]
}
```

Thanks

Comment: what you have tried ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tried best....just use  [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/)

```
db.ctrlcharts.aggregate(
{$unwind:"$charts"},
{$match: {"deviceId" :"A001", "charts.sensor":"ch_12", "time" : "2016/10/11 12:23:50"}},
{$project:{_id:0,time:1, sensor : "$charts.sensor", value :"$charts.value"}}).pretty()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$unwind (aggregation)` to separate charts array.

```
db.ctrlcharts.aggregate( [ { $unwind : "$charts" } ] )
```

This will produce result like -

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57ff397a007c43ecacf10512"), "deviceId" : "A001", "sensorId" : "S003", "time" : "2016/10/11 12:23:50", "charts" : { "sensor" : "ch_11", "value" : 120 } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57ff397a007c43ecacf10512"), "deviceId" : "A001", "sensorId" : "S003", "time" : "2016/10/11 12:23:50", "charts" : { "sensor" : "ch_12", "value" : 150 } }
```

and then use your match query

Answer (score 0):

Use the **[`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/)** and **[`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/#exp._S_filter)** operators to query the array more efficiently without the need to **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind)**. The reason why  **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind)** is not as efficient is that it produces a cartesian product of the documents i.e. a copy of each document per array entry, which uses more memory (possible memory cap on aggregation pipelines of 10% total memory) and therefore takes time to produce as well processing the documents during the flattening process.

The **[`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/#exp._S_filter)** will return a subset of the array that only contains the elements that match the filter condition. The **[`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/)** operator then returns the element from the filtered array at the specified array index to give you the subdocument you need.

A further **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** is necessary to flatten the fields to give you the desired result:

```
db.ctrlcharts.aggregate([
    { "$match": { 
        "deviceId": "A001", 
        "sensorId": "S003", 
        "time": "2016/10/11 12:23:50",
        "charts.sensor": "ch_11"
    } },
    { 
        "$project": { 
            "time": 1, 
            "chart": {
                "$arrayElemAt": [
                    "$filter": {
                        "input": "$charts",
                        "as": "item",
                        "cond": { "$eq": ["$$item.sensor", "ch_11"] }
                    }, 0
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    { 
        "$project": { 
            "_id": 0,
            "time": 1, 
            "sensor": "$chart.sensor"
            "value": "$chart.value"
        }
    } 
])
```